# Best way to create this Streamlined shape and windows?

Tags: modeling, mesh, bevel, extrude, smooth

Good afternoon all,

I'm interested in your takes on the best way to create this nose and cab frame?

[image]

Am I better to extrude it from a single cube or use multiple components? I'm not used to fiddling with shapes so streamlined.

Anyone got some steps in the right direction? It needs to have windows as well, which is making it fiddlier for me.

Thanks all. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Begin with a cube, cut it in half and mirror, extrude its bottom:

[image]

Add edge loops and move them:

[image]

Bevel in order to round the edges:

[image]

Extrude the windows, etc:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! :) Thank worked pretty much how I wanted it too. Feel bad for wasting your time with such an easy thing haha Thanks :)

Comment: you're welcome, it's not so easy, but planes are worse I think  ;)

Comment: You up for a more difficult one? I have one other that I think is even worse to get my head around haha

Comment: why not, but create a new question

Comment: Its up haha :) See how this goes